# Not able to connect to MySQL with Docker container name but can connect with localhost

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am not able to connect to MySQL using Docker container name in connection string but can connect with localhost.

**docker-compose:**

```
 mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql

  app:
    image: app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-docker-container

links:
  - mysql-docker-container:mysql-docker-container
ports:
  - 9090:9090
volumes:
  - /data/p2c-app
environment:
  - DATABASE_HOST=mysql-docker-container
  - DATABASE_USER=testuser
  - DATABASE_PASWORD=testuser
  - DATABASE_NAME=test
  - DATABASE_PORT=3306

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Above works, but I want with container name like below - I am getting CONNECTION REFUSED

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/test?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you "the above works" (referring to `mysql://localhost:3306`), where are you running that? That will work on your host, since you've published the port, but I assume you want to make a connection from your `app` container.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `/etc/hosts` if localhost connection works.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost  mysql-docker-container
```

To check whether `mysql-docker-container` is reachable from the app container you can open a tty and ping.

```
docker exec -it app_container_name bash
ping mysql-docker-container
```

Comment: The question author does not want to connect to localhost - their app and database are correctly in different containers. They want to connect from one container to another.

Comment: I think he is trying to connect from outside of a container like spring boot framework `spring.datasource.url`

Comment: Ah, apologies - I see what you mean - you're suggesting he/she is wanting to connect from the host, not from a container. Yes, that would explain why localhost works, and why they don't need to change it. (I have made a clarification to your post, re-edit if it's not what you meant).

Comment: Guys, i dont want to connect to localhost but from docker container. This should clearly explain : jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/

Comment: Are you running the spring app inside a container?

Comment: you have published your MySQL connection to port 3306 on the `host machine(127.0.0.1)` by using `ports: -3306:3306`. `127.0.0.1:3306` is the only way to connect to MySQL, you have options to map `127.0.0.1` to a specific name like localhost, mysql-docker-container as per your need in the etc/hosts file

Comment: @minhazur tried without publishing the port as well...i was able to connect with container name with only using dockerfile using link command but having issues with dockercompose..but thank you for your efforts

Comment: Hi, I have just tried with this https://pastebin.com/GNLsqR0s file that's created based on your compose file and linking working as expected. Maybe your compose file has a formatting issue or Dockerfile is doing something unexpected. Please, share your app's Dockerfile content as well.

Comment: "I dont want to connect to localhost but from docker container" - please merge in this clarification into your original post. I have downvoted it, and will upvote once it is amended - thanks!

Comment: With this new information, it is worth noting that the publishing of ports will make no difference. Containers on the same network do not notice if ports are published to the host or not - if you do not also wish to access the MySQL server from your host (e.g. in MySQL WorkBench) then you can remove the `ports` at `3306:3306` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok.
It seems the database service is up but the mysql is in the startup process.
And the app service starts up then and can not reach to the database.

There are some workarounds for this situation.
But the simple one is that you add below to app service.

```
restart: on-failure
```

And note that `depends_on` section just means in docker container context not in underlying services.